# Class method not working properly in draw() in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm writing some code in Processing, and basically what I'm trying to do is get a blue square to "light up" (change to a lighter shade), and then back again. I wrote a superclass and a subclass, with a method in the subclass that's intended to do this lighting up business. Here's the code:

**Superclass**

```
abstract class Squares {
  color darkBlue = color(0, 0, 204);
  color brightBlue = color(0, 0, 255);

  Squares(float x, float y) {
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
  }

  float _x;
  float _y;
  color _c;

  abstract void drawSquare();

  abstract void brighten();

  abstract void darken();
}
```

**Subclass**

```
class blueSquare extends Squares {
  blueSquare(float x, float y) {
    super(x, y);
    _c = darkBlue;
  }

  void drawSquare() {
    fill(_c);
    rect(_x, _y, 240, 240);
  }

  void brighten() {
    _c = brightBlue;
    this.drawSquare();
  }

  void darken() {
    _c = darkBlue;
    this.drawSquare();
  }

  void onOff() {
    this.brighten();
    delay(500);
    this.darken();
  }

  String toString() {
    return ("Blue color is" + _c);
  }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
blueSquare blueSquare = new blueSquare(310, 310);

void setup() {
  background(50);
  size(600, 600);
  drawSquares();
}

void draw() {
  blueSquare.onOff();
  println(blueSquare);
}

void drawSquares() {
  strokeWeight(5);
  blueSquare.drawSquare();
}
```

The `onOff()` method will only work at all (as in the color actually changing, as evidence by the `println`) in `setup()` and only if there is no `delay()` before it. How can I get this to work properly in `draw()` so that I can have it flash when I press a button, click the mouse, etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use delay inside draw, it won't work because draw will draw last color (it won't be called till everything is ended). I'll use a thread and a flag. The thread can wait that 500ms and then change the flag. Everytime you draw the rectangle you check that flag and change color filling. 
You can check thread in the reference.

Make this changes and it will work (leave Squares unchanged):

superclass:

```
blueSquare blue = new blueSquare(310, 310);

void setup() {
  background(50);
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() 
{
  strokeWeight(5);
  blue.drawSquare();
}

void mousePressed()
{
  thread("onOff");    
}

void onOff()
{
  blue.flashing();
  delay(500);
  blue.noFlashing();
}
```

blueSquare

```
class blueSquare extends Squares 
{
  boolean _flashing;
  blueSquare(float x, float y) 
  {
    super(x, y);
    this._c = darkBlue;
    this._flashing=false;
  }

  void drawSquare() 
  {
    if (this._flashing)
    {
      this._c=brightBlue;
    }
    else
    {
      this._c=darkBlue;
    }
    fill(_c);
    rect(_x, _y, 240, 240);
  }

  void brighten() 
  {
    this._c = brightBlue;
    this.drawSquare();
  }

  void darken() {
    _c = darkBlue;
    this.drawSquare();
  }

  String toString() 
  {
    return ("Blue color is" + _c);
  }

  void flashing()
  {
    this._flashing=true;
  }

  void noFlashing()
  {
    this._flashing=false;
  }
```

}

Comment: MousePressed: when you press the mouse you call a thread, that thread doesn't alter the normal execution of draw.

Comment: OnOff executes in that thread, changing a value inside blueSquare. that square decides which color uses based on that boolean variable.

Comment: You should definitely not use another thread for this. Processing comes with variables and functions that allow you to integrate timing into your sketch. Just use those instead.

Comment: I'm not on windows. Threads are very light. Using threads on windows is atrocious.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what OS you're on. You shouldn't use threads for this. This is exactly what `millis()` and `frameCount` are meant for. Use them instead.

Comment: Yours is a nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `delay()` function in an animated sketch. You should also not use separate threads.

Instead, use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable to add timing to your animations.

Here is a simple example that shows a square that you can turn green for 1 second at a time:

```
int startFrame;
int duration = 60;
boolean on = false;

void draw() {
  if (on) {
    background(0, 255, 0);
  } else {
    background(0, 0, 255);
  }

  if (startFrame + duration < frameCount) {
    on = false;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  startFrame = frameCount;
  on = true;
}
```

Please note that this is just an example, but you can use these concepts to set up timing in your animations.